# Virtualenv :WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I'm working with miniconda and git=bash on win7. I'm trying to make a virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv myenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "e:\miniconda2\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1202, in install_python
    mkdir(bin_dir)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 323, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "e:\miniconda2\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'e:\\ENVS\\virtalenvs\\myenv\\Scripts'
```

How can I get this working?